# Android Studio not found Vernee Apollo Lite device

Tags: android-studio, device

My android studio not detects Vernee Apollo Lite, I activate **android developer options** with **usb debugging** and my android versio is 6.0. My operative system is **windows 7** and when connects the usb, windows install a driver...

Then I try to compile with android studio and doesn't detects this device, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed the USB driver that came with the Android SDK?

Comment: If you referred to universal usb driver from google, the answer is yes... Thanks!

Comment: Another thing you can check is which protocol the device is using for connection. Using PTP instead of MTP worked for my device.

Comment: Thanks halileohalilei!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution... I install this [Vernee thor driver](http://singledrivers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/vernee-thor-4g-lte-usb-driver-for.html) and using PTP instead of MTP connection (Thanks halileohalilei), now I cand develop!